# Live update php variable and simultaneously, show the value in a textbox

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

This is my table row click function in the file, 'BAConsult.php'. On click, showconsultationdata function will run.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //table row click
  }).on('click','.consultclick tr',function(e){   
      if(e.target.tagName === "TD"){
          $(".consultclick tr").removeClass("highlight");
    $(e.target).parent().addClass("highlight");    
      }      
    var dateconsulted = $(this).attr('value'); 
    alert(dateconsulted);
    showconsultationdata(dateconsulted);
});
```

This is my ajax script

```
function showconsultationdata(str) { 
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint2").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint2").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; 

        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","BAConsultRecordsAJAX.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}
```

Here is another php file called 'BAConsultRecordsAJAX.php' where i placed the ajax of the showconsultationdata.

```
session_start();
require('Config/Setup.php');
$q = $_GET['q']; 
$consult="SELECT * FROM Counsel where nric='$_SESSION[nric]' and dateconsulted='$q'";

$consultresult = mysqli_query($dbconn,$consult);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consultresult)) {
$skincareremarks=$row['skincareremarks'];
$skinconditionremarks=$row['skinconditionremarks'];
}
```

On table row click, $skincareremarks and $skinconditionremarks should be updated. And these values will show up in the textboxes in the 'BAConsult.php' page. How can i do this?

Comment: and your ajax script?

Comment: @madalinivascu i've just updated my post, check it out

Comment: in `BACondultRecordsAJAX.php` you need to `echo` what you want to be returned as 'responseText'.

Comment: @Jeff may i know how do i do this? sorry... im not good at this, im new to website programming

Comment: short answer: `echo $skincareremarks;`. You will want to have those two values in an array, then json_encode it and echo that. In ajax script `JSON.parse(responseText)`. Loads of manuals/tutorials on that [topic](https://www.google.com/#q=php+ajax+example+json)!

Comment: @Jeff I've tried it. But it seems that in the script, this code doesn't run... var a = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

Comment: @Jeff hey man, thanks i managed to did it with JSON and solved the JSON code problem! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i followed @Jeff's method by using JSON. However, I realised that the xmlhttp.responseText wasn't only showing my JSON encoded code, but also my javascript which was why the JSON.parse method was unable run properly. I then did the following:

In my BAConsultRecordsAJAX.php file, i did this.

```
echo "<div id='test1'>";
echo json_encode(array('first'=>$skincareremarks,'second'=>$skinconditionremarks));
echo "</div>";
```

I gave this output a div called 'test1'.

Then, in my main file's AJAX script, i did this.

```
var a = JSON.parse($(xmlhttp.responseText).filter('#test1').html());    
document.getElementById("test").value=a.first;
```

So basically, it filters out the rest of the xhtmlhttp.responseText outputs, and selects only the contents in the div where id='test1'.

Hope this helps those who have this problem too..